# Is it ok to have two rows of bars?

Tags: interaction-design, navigation, interface

In my standard desktop browser based app, there is a menu bar with a set of essentials buttons (Search, New Search, New Request, etc). Below that, I have added a bar that enables users to organize and easily access their macros.

The bar is there to save users' time, so it needs to be easily accessible. However, I'm not sure if two rows of menus are a great idea.

What do you think? Any alternative solutions that come to your mind?

[image: Standard Bar plus Macro Bar]

Answer (score 1):

If both bars are equally important and the second bar does not depend on the first one (like the second one is a sub menu of the first one or something like that), I wouldn't place them underneath but next to each other. As this would obviously not work with the current design you could think of putting them into tabs. Just think of how all the Microsoft Office programs do it.

Comment: Tabs came to my mind as well, but a) the consume quite some space and b) I have way to many options for tabs...

Answer (score 1):

I **would not** recommend using two rows of menu bars especially since they are not directly linked.

I recommend using keeping the top navigation menu and moving your second row to a left sided vertical menu bar. You can see and example here:

[image]

This software has both a left and right sided panel for extended options and a main top navigation bar.